# File upload - permission denied (PHP) and cannot change permission

Tags: php

I have uploaded my website to my university server through FileZilla. When I was trying to upload an image, it gave me errors. (when testing in localhost it worked fine)

```
move_uploaded_file(images/a1d91430cf89bfcaa1a5fa953ebab2dc000e0eed.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpF1v2O3' to 'images/a1d91430cf89bfcaa1a5fa953ebab2dc000e0eed.jpg'
```

and here is the coding

```
if (!array_key_exists('image', $add_image_errors)) {
    $new_name= (string) sha1($file['name'] . uniqid('',true));
    $new_name .= ((substr($ext, 0, 1) != '.') ? ".{$ext}" : $ext);
    $dest = "images/$new_name";
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest)) {
        $_SESSION['image']['new_name'] = $new_name;
        $_SESSION['image']['file_name'] = $file['name'];
        echo '<h4>The file has been uploaded!</h4>';
            } else {
                trigger_error('The file could not be moved.');
                unlink ($file['tmp_name']);
                }
            } // End of array_key_exists( ) IF.
```

I have looked at number of forums and understand that it was the problem with file permission. Therefore I changed the permission for image folder from FileZilla (755 to 777) )however it didn't allow me to change for some reason.

Then I tried to add chmod ("images",0777), but I gave me the same error - chmod(): Permission denied

and here is the coding

```
    $dest = "images/$new_name";
    chmod ("images",0777);
```

any ideas on how to change the permission or any alternatives in the coding so that images can be uploaded and written in image folder?

I am new to PHP

many thanks

Comment: You may not have permission to change the file permissions.  Additionally, I've seen this flavor of an error when the server was a Windows server running php.

Comment: The University's server may not allow you or anyone to perform any special tasks. Contact the sysadmin.

Comment: Looks like it's out of your control. Not surprising on a university system. Imagine how destroyed their system could be if they let any novice upload whatever they wanted.

Comment: I was just thinking that too. @KaiQing

Comment: Are you certain that the directory `image/` exists?

Comment: yes definitely images folder exists

Comment: i think this is a problem with permissions in tmp directory of your server. In some shared hosts we don't have permission to use tmp_dir... Make a fake tmp dir in your root project folder and try to change your tmp dir with `ini_set('upload-tmp-dir', __DIR__ . '/tmp');` Don't forget to apply `chmod 777` to new tmp dir.

Answer (score 1):

Your system administrator seems to have imposed restrictions on the way your scripts can modify the filesystem. Especially in a University environment, tight security controls are necessary in order to prevent an internal and external breaches brought on by poorly-written or malicious code written by a student or faculty member.

More specifically, `chmod(): Permission denied` indicates that your sysadmin has deliberately prohibited changing file permissions in PHP.

In short, you are being restricted in order to prevent naughty things from occurring on the University's server.

Answer (score 0):

In shared hosts, sometimes, you haven't permissions to read and write from default temp directory, try change your temp directory to some folder of your project as:

```
ini_set('upload-tmp-dir', '/real/path/of/your/directory');
```